# Command to List *nix Group Members?

Tags: linux, unix

What's the command to figure out who the members are of a *nix group?

Comment: It's normally spelled Un*x.

Comment: Depends on where you look. I've definitely seen that spelling before. To be technically correct, *n*x would be most accurate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

depending on the environment, for secondary groups here are some options.:

"**getent group | grep** *^groupname:*"  (getent - get entries from administrative database)

"**ypcat group | grep** *^groupname:*"  (ypcat - print values of all keys in a NIS database)

"**grep** *^groupname:* **/etc/group**"  (/etc/group is the local group file)

and if you just want the name of the group and the users add "**| cut -d: -f1,4**" to the end of the string (example: **grep** ^*groupname*: **/etc/group | cut -d: -f1,4**)

The primary group id is listed in the **passwd** file entry for each user, so the user's primary groups won't show up in the output of any of the commands listed above.  You could "**grep** *^groupname:* **/etc/group | cut -d: -f1,3**" to get the groupid number, then "**grep** *:groupidnumber:* **/etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1**" to get the user's account name.

Comment: Or you can just do `getent group <groupname>` instead of the first three lines of greppage.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep ^<groupname>: /etc/group
```